# MS Access Module

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hello I am fairly new to VBA coding in MS Access and I keep running into an issue with a data transfer module. I believe the issue is with the 'DoCmd.RunSQL line' however I cannot pinpoint how to fix it. The code is as follow:

```
    Public Function runit()

    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", "C:\Documents and Settings\LChristi\Desktop\Projections Sep 2013\2-Transpose and Break into Counties\2c-BreakIntoCountiesTransposed.mdb", acTable, "CNTY999", "CNTY999"

    cnty = Left(Right(CurrentDb.Name, 7), 3)

    DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into TBLCNTY" & cnty & " (UI, RU, Year, Month, County, NAICS, Owner, MEEI, Emp, AdjCnty, AdjNAICS, ADJEMP)Select UI, RU, Year, Month, County, NAICS, Owner, MEEI, Emp, AdjCnty,AdjNAICS,AdjEMP from CNTY" & cnty & "';"

    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "CNTY" & cnty & ""

    End Function
```

When I attempt to run said module, I get an Error '3024' could not find file message back. This data base has been moved from one computer to mine. I was wondering if anyone knows how I could go about resolving this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a pure SQL solution as Access can query from other Access databases with inline calls. No need for DoCmd.* commands. Also, be sure to escape reserved words like *Month* and *Year*. Please fill in placeholders below:

```sql
INSERT INTO myLocalTable (UI, RU, [Year], [Month], County, NAICS, Owner, MEEI, Emp, 
                          AdjCnty, AdjNAICS, ADJEMP)
SELECT UI, RU, [Year], [Month], County, NAICS, Owner, MEEI, Emp, AdjCnty, AdjNAICS, AdjEMP 
FROM [C:\Path\To\External\Database.accdb].[myExternalTable]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time.  The issue, I think, is that we kind of need to use a variable "cnty = Left(Right(CurrentDb.Name, 7), 3)"  that represents a county number (e.g., 001, 101, 203).  This is being pulled from the database name... and then used in the DoCmd.  A simple insert works, but we need to be able to incorporate the variable piece.  So, the following code works
insert into TBLCNTY001 (UI, RU, Year, Month, County, NAICS, Owner, MEEI, Emp, AdjCnty, AdjNAICS, ADJEMP)
 Select UI, RU, Year, Month, County, NAICS, Owner, MEEI, Emp, AdjCnty,AdjNAICS,AdjEMP 
 from CNTY001;

Answer (score 0):

you have a double space in filepath  between `and` and `Settings`  in "Documents and 
 Settings"

Comment: that was an error in typing the coding on here, in access there is no extra space, I just edited my original question.